# Instagram and Selenium. How to Click Lightbox?

Tags: python, css, selenium-webdriver, instagram

I'm creating a Python script that helps users in Instagram engagement groups to quickly like everyone's photo in each round. The problem I'm having is when I get to a user's profile, I can't figure out how to make Selenium click the first photo.

For example on https://www.instagram.com/earthpix/ if you click the first photo, it's more of a lightbox effect. I tried finding a relevant CSS selector but it fails everytime.

However it does have a unique URL "https://www.instagram.com/p/Bm023pTFeLq/?taken-by=earthpix"

My goal is to determine this URL and have Selenium navigate it. So then I can easily click the heart icon.

Any tips here?

PS if you want to see the current status I created a repo on Github.

https://github.com/nfordhk/instaHacks/blob/engagementGroups-autoRounds/engagementGroups.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code below gets all A elements. You can click and like in loop.

```
photos = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('article a')
for photo in photos:
    photo.click()
    #like
    #close photo
```

Tested code:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/earthpix/");

List<WebElement> photos = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("article a"));
for (WebElement p:photos) {
    p.click();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! I gave it a try but it says it cannot find css_selector 'article a'